# Unable to find setter method for attribute in jstl

Tags: jstl, jsp-tags, custom-tags

I'm having trouble with a custom tag.  i am getting this error

```
/test.jsp (line: 10, column: 4) Unable to find setter method for attribute: url
```

Here is Code :

The TagHandlerClass :

```
package net.viralpatel.jsp.custom.taglib;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport;

public class SubstrTagHandler extends TagSupport {
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String url;
    private String videoId;
    private String listId;
    private boolean bOpenNewWindow;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getVideoId() {
        return videoId;
    }

    public void setVideoId(String videoId) {
        this.videoId = videoId;
    }

    public String getListId() {
        return listId;
    }

    public void setListId(String listId) {
        this.listId = listId;
    }

    public boolean isbOpenNewWindow() {
        return bOpenNewWindow;
    }

    public void setbOpenNewWindow(boolean bOpenNewWindow) {
        this.bOpenNewWindow = bOpenNewWindow;
    }

    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
        try {
            //Get the writer object for output.
            JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();

            if (null != url && !url.trim().equals("")) {
                StringBuffer resultURL = new StringBuffer();
                resultURL.append("<a href=" + url);

                //this is internal URL and not poiniting to dam so need to append .html
                if (url.startsWith("/") && !url.contains("/dam/")) {
                    resultURL.append(".html");

                }
                if ((videoId != null && !videoId.trim().equals("")) || (listId != null && !listId.trim().equals(""))) {
                    if ((videoId != null && !videoId.trim().equals(""))) {
                        resultURL.append("?vcID=" + videoId);
                    } else if (listId != null && !listId.trim().equals("")) {
                        resultURL.append("?listID=" + listId);
                    }
                }
                if (bOpenNewWindow) {
                    resultURL.append(" target=_blank");
                }

                resultURL.append("></a>");
                //Perform substr operation on string.
                out.println(resultURL);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }
}
```

My TLD FIle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib> 
<tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
<jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
<shortname>Sublink</shortname>
<info>Sample taglib for Video Link operation</info>
<tag>
    <name>link</name>
    <tagclass>net.viralpatel.jsp.custom.taglib.SubstrTagHandler</tagclass>
    <info>Substring function.</info>
    <attribute>
      <name>url</name>
      <required>false</required>
  </attribute>
    <attribute>
      <name>videoId</name>
      <required>false</required>
  </attribute>
    <attribute>
      <name>listId</name>
      <required>false</required>
  </attribute>
  <attribute>
     <name>bOpenNewWindow</name>
      <required>false</required>
  </attribute>
</tag>
</taglib>
```

Here is JSP File

```
<%@taglib prefix="test" uri="/WEB-INF/lib/SubstrLink.tld"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSP Custom Taglib example: Substr function</title>
</head>
<body>
    SUBSTR(GOODMORNING, 1, 6) is 
    <font color="blue">
    <test:link url="www.google.com" videoId="1" listId="6" bOpenNewWindow="true"/>
    </font>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not see any evident error.

Comment: But it is not working .giving a error as mention in heading

Comment: Is the SubstrTagHandler correctly compiled and deployed into web application?

Comment: Can't see an issue with the `url` property. For the `bOpenNewWindow` property though I would have thought the set method should be named `setBOpenNewWindow`.